# How to solve matrix differential equations problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I need to solve
$$\begin{bmatrix}
   20 & 6 \\
   6 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   y''_1 \\
   y''_2
  \end{bmatrix} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   40 \\
   15
  \end{bmatrix}$$

And I'm not entirely sure how.  If the vector $\begin{bmatrix}y''_1 \\y''_2\end{bmatrix}$ were just denoted $\mathbf y''$, my guess would be that the solution should be of the form $\mathbf y = Cx+D +$ some particular solution.  However, I have no idea how I'm supposed to find $C, D$ and $\mathbf y_p$.  In fact, I'm not entirely sure what $C$ and $D$ should be.  I guess they're $2\times 1$ columns because that's the only thing that makes sense ($y_1, y_2$ are both functions of the single variable $x$).  This came up outside of an ODEs class and I don't remember ever covering this type of problem.  What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Isn't this just $20y_1''+6y_2''=40$ and $6y_1''+7y_2''=15$? Solving two simultaneous equations?

Comment: Yes.  I could extract the scalar equations if that's easier.

Comment: Start by multiplying both sides by the inverse of  $$\begin{bmatrix}
   20 & 6 \\
   6 & 7
  \end{bmatrix} $$ and then things will be straightforward.

Comment: This is just a linear system (that derivatives appear is not relevant to the linear system), you can easily solve it to find $y''_1$ and $y''_2$ (they are constants), then integrate twice.

Comment: you can consider $y_i"$ as algebraic variable

Comment: Oh okay.  Thanks.